# Azure Function throws exception before it hits my code (operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function that is triggered via Http, sometimes requests fail with the following exception being thrown:

> Exception while executing function: **********
> Exception binding parameter 'request'
> The client has disconnected An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection. (0x800704CD)

My code looks like this, but I'm pretty sure the request is not getting this far:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> MyFunctionAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest request, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(request, nameof(request));
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(log, nameof(log));
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(context, nameof(context));

        // More processing...

        return new OkObjectResult("MyFunction completed successfully");
    }
}
```

To add to the confusion there are other functions within the solution that never throw this exception -- this function is the ONLY function that throws the exception.

I have tried several ways to find the source of the exception to no avail.

Comment: Did you try debugging the code?

Comment: I tried debugging the code, but the exception happens before my code gets called.

Answer (score 0):

> Exception while executing function: **********
> Exception binding parameter 'request'
> The client has disconnected An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection. (0x800704CD)

There could be delay in processing the request or the client closing the connection in the middle of uploading a request body.

- Enclose the code with try-catch blocks and handle the exceptions.
- Place a breakpoint at:

```cs
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
```

Debug and check if you are able to hit the breakpoint and check the request value.

[image]

- Set "functionTimeout" in host.json and run the function:

**host.json:**

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  },
  "functionTimeout": "00:30:00"
}
```

- Sign out and sign back in with Azure credentials in Visual Studio.

[image]

- Configure Azure Application Insights to log the exceptions of your Function.